# What's wrong with my variable definition in Google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have pushed some values into the dataLayer as you can see below, I have them on google tag manager debugging console:

[image]

I have defined a custom javascript variable like this:

```
function() {
    var dest;
    dest = google_tag_manager[{{Container 
    ID}}].dataLayer.get("DestinationLocation").fromLocation;
    return dest;
 }
```

but still, it's undefined in the variable list.

[image]

Comment: Could you please also include, how you push this variable into dataLayer?

Comment: I push them using javascript when trigerring a button:
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({'event': 'something'});
</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get a reference to the tag manager object, and while this works in tags it does not work in variables.

There is no reason why this should work - if the value is on the dataLayer (either via a push, or via the datalayer.set method) you can just create a dataLayer variable that will return the value. No need for any custom scripting.

Answer (score 1):

In your case **DestinationLocation** is a **custom event**, so to detect it you have to create a custom event with name *DestinationLocation* and use it as a trigger to fires the desired tag.